# Node global tunnel and loggly and linkerd

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, loggly, linkerd

I'm using linkerd and have to use `global tunnel` to proxy everything via `localhost:4140`. The problem is that this seems to cause loggly to stop working. As soon as the global tunnel is active, loggly doesn't receive any messages. How can I change it?

```
globalTunnel.initialize({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4140
});
```

I have seen, that I can pass a proxy variable in the config for the `loggy` instance.

```
var logglyStream = new Bunyan2Loggly(logglyConfig);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`globalTunnel` overrides all http requests, so assuming that the Loggly library uses the standard `http` library, further proxy configuration in the Loggly library is not necessary.

I think there may be two issues here:

### Linkerd Routing Rules

linkerd needs routing rules to proxy to the outside internet. You'll need a [dtab](https://linkerd.io/in-depth/dtabs/) that recognizes `host:port` requests and routes them accordingly:

```yaml
dtab: |
  /ip-hostport => /$/inet;
  /svc => /$/io.buoyant.hostportPfx/ip-hostport;
```

Confirm routing works with this command:

```bash
$ http_proxy=localhost:4140 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" www.google.com:80
200
```

### Loggly header processing

It appears that Loggly fails all requests that contain headers with forward slashes in them:

```bash
# working request:
$ curl -H "foo: bar" -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" logs-01.loggly.com
403

# failed request:
$ curl -H "foo: /bar" -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" logs-01.loggly.com
400
```

Linkerd sets several headers on outbound requests for tracing, service discovery, and context information. Some of those headers include strings with forward slashes.

To get around this, we have two options:

1. Modify linkerd to clear headers on outbound requests. I've filed github.com/linkerd/linkerd/issues/1218 to track this work.
2. Set up a proxy server to handle outbound requests for Loggly, as documented in https://github.com/loggly/loggly-jslogger#setup-proxy-for-ad-blockers. Then, assuming that service is set up at `internal-nginx-proxy`, you can use this routing rule:

```yaml
dtab: |
  /svc/logs-01.loggly.com => /$/inet/internal-nginx-proxy/80;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with linkerd but it sends logs to logs-01.loggly.com either on port 80 or 443 for secure. Is that proxied through your tunnel?